# How to write a matrix norm?

Tags: matrices

I want to write a matrix but instead of brackets, I want it to be a norm. How do I do this? 
So instead of [] in a normal matrix, I want || ||.

Comment: `\left\|\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}\right\|`

Comment: "[] in a normal matrix" How are you doing that?  There's several ways.

Comment: @David Carlisle thanks that worked sorry I didnt think it was so simply

Comment: You have the `Vmatrix` environment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose among many different matrix enviornments in LaTeX.  Here are your choices:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{multicols}{3}
  matrix  $\begin{matrix}  a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{matrix}$

  pmatrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{pmatrix}$

  bmatrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{bmatrix}$

  Bmatrix $\begin{Bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{Bmatrix}$

  vmatrix $\begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{vmatrix}$

  Vmatrix $\begin{Vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{Vmatrix}$
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]