# How to represent norm (Vert) that changes size based on the inside, in LyX?

Tags: lyx, brackets

When using the standard brackets, such as [ { ( |, I write ctrl-| and get two | surrounding an expression. If that expression's height changes (fractions could cause that), then the brackets grows as well.

[image]

If I want to represent normal, it appear that the proper solution is to write \Vert before and after. However, in this case, the brackets do not grow.

[image]

I could simply create two | surrounding the expression

[image]

But the bars are too far apart, and I would prefer one action to create the double bars.

Is there a way?

Note: When following [How to write a matrix norm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368056/how-to-write-a-matrix-norm) I see the solution is write \Vmatrix , but that produces

[image]

which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert > Math Delimiters and click on "||", keep the "Keep matched" box checked and make sure "Variable" is chosen. "Variable" is what means it adapts to the size of its contents.

Comment: thanks. Is there a keyword that I can type to add that? So that I can use the symbol easier

Comment: Yes, you can use the command `math-delim Vert Vert`. You can make a shortcut attached to that command.